# Add property to application.properties for "mvnw clean package"?

Tags: java, spring, maven

While debugging in STS, I need property xxx.yyy.zzz to either be / or not there at all. However, when deploying to Tomcat via mvnw clean package, I need to add xxx.yyy.zzz=/myApp

I saw a SO overflow post that says you just need to do:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <xxx.yyy.zzz>/myApp</xxx.yyy.zzz>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But that doesn't work. I've been reading up on profiles, but I think that is overkill for my needs, I don't want to maintain multiple copies of the properties, I just want to override that one property. Is there a way to do the profiles where you just have values to override?

This is for a spring boot app.

**EDIT:**

Based on Khalil's suggestion, I am trying profiles.

1) I added application-tomcat.properties

2) In pom.xml, I added:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.properties.active>tomcat</spring.properties.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

3) I did mvnw clean package -P tomcat

No errors, and the deployment went fine, but its not reading the property.

Comment: it's not "mvmw clean package". it's mvn clean package.

Comment: You need to override if it is existing? To what? Another value? I understood that you need it to be there or not at all!? What's the third option?

Comment: @pkm On Windows its mvnw

Comment: And how would two profiles with the good values of this property will overkill your needs, this is exactly why profiles was invented for

Comment: @KhalilM My application.properties contains ~40 properties. While debugging in STS, xxx.yyy.zzz should either not be in the application.properties or it should be / (/ is the default, so its not needed). When deploying to tomcat, the app is no longer in the root, so this needs to be adjusted to /myApp. If I do profiles, the two files must contain ALL properties, correct? Seems like a pain vs. just overriding the one I need.

Comment: @KhalilM Also, don't profiles copy out ALL files to ALL environments? Or just the specific one?

Comment: I believe you have design issues such thing shouldn't be in property file, but to answer your question have you tried putting it in one profile, the other not? Have you tried putting it as empty string?

Comment: Profiles are a way of controlling properties, is high-level check, properties file should be along with the app but depending on your code just will grab the needed value depending on your conditions

Comment: @KhalilM Not my design. Its a starter. The WebUI defaults to /webui. In Tomcat, it needs to be /myApp/webui. There isn't a way to override it in code, look at the code in github, that property is in the javascript and they replace it in the mapReplacements method.

Comment: @KhalilM I added a application-tomcat.properties, but mvnw clean package, the war includes both .properties. It is a secops violation to have env1 properties exposed on env2. Not this one obviously, but I also have usernames and passwords in there for DB connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with this solution?

**application-root.properties**

> xxx.yyy.zzz=/

**application-not-root.properties**

```
bla bla

@Profile("root")
public String xxYY(){
return yourVar;
}

@Profile("Notroot")
public String xxYY(){
return "";
}

if (your condition){
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("root or no root");
}
```

or even this if you're talking about Tomcat:

```
if (your condition)
servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "root or no root");
```

Comment: The property is not mine... it belongs to a starter. I am trying to implement the profiles as you suggested, but it is not working... please see my question edit.

Comment: how are you accessing the value?

Comment: I am not directly... I am using a starter and the starter includes a controller which accesses it through @Value("${xxx.yyy.zzz:}")

Comment: So add your annotation there as in the response @profile